# Python 2.7.5 - Where is it installed on Windows Vista?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I downloaded Python 2.7.5 and tried everything on Google to find Python in command prompt. I failed. Any help with this? I have a Windows Vista 32 bit OS.

Comment: What do you mean "find python in command prompt?" Do you need to find the directory it installs to? Does it not run from the command line?

Comment: actually no. all i keep getting is 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file. thanks Grinner!

Comment: You have to go to Windows>>Setting>>EnvironmentVariables, python has to be added to your path, so the command promt will recognize it.

Comment: thanks Leon. I did try that too. In Env variables, I clicked on new and then have both variable name and variable value. I typed in C in name and then ;\python in value. did not work. is the problem here?

Comment: What I am trying to do here is to see if the ex1.py file I created in Notepad++ can be displayed in the command prompt.thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default install location for Python-2.7 on Windows is: C:\Python27

Therefore you can:

```
c:
cd \Python27
python
```

Comment: hey fuzzy, ok..that seemed to work.

Comment: Thanks. in my command prompt, I now have >>>. If I need to find "python ex1.py" should I just type in this

Comment: `>>>` indicates you're in the interactive Python interpreter. If you need to be able to call Python from any directory, you will need to add Python to the PATH. See http://showmedo.com/videotutorials/video?name=960000&fromSeriesID=96 or many other sources for adding a program to PATH

Comment: You should type that at the command prompt, not in the Python shell. :)

Comment: thanks guys, but i only see one of the 7 lines (the last one) that I typed in the notepad.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add it as an environment variable.

Everything is in the Python Tutorial of how to install in Windows

http://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html