# Not able to install Python 2.7.9 on Windows Vista machine

Tags: python, windows, installation, windows-vista

I am not able to install Python 2.7.9 on Windows Vista machine & getting below error.

There is a problem with Windows installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.

Can you please help me resolving this issue ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGugN.png)

Comment: Windows Vista comes with Python, generally located in C:\Python27. It's version 2.7.5. Do you actually need version 2.7.9? If 2.7.5 is sufficient, I recommend looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236630/python-2-7-5-where-is-it-installed-on-windows-vista to try to get python running.

Comment: Python is not installed on it. I want 2.7.9 version to be installed. I just don't understand why it does not get installed on it. Python 2.7.9 was installed successfully on Windows XP also.

Comment: How do you know that Python is not in stalled on your machine?

Comment: Check 1: Python or python.exe is not available anywhere . Check 2: ran "python" in command prompt did not work. Check 3: Control panel has no entry for python.

Comment: what happens if you run the commands in the answer in this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236630/python-2-7-5-where-is-it-installed-on-windows-vista

Comment: @KatyaHandler, Python isn't distributed with any version of Windows. `C:\Python27` is the default installation directory used by the 2.7 installer.

Comment: Try running the installer from an elevated (run as administrator) command prompt: `msiexec /i path\to\msi`.

Answer (score 0):

You can open start menu (tap on e.g windows key) and type the name of the program you're looking for, so in this case 'python'. If you have that program already on your computer, it will show.

Comment: No , Python is not installed on this machine.

Comment: You may be able to proceed using pip to install Python. Please look at this discussion at SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows?rq=1

Comment: My problem is to install Python. pip comes within Python. How how come pip will install Python ?

Comment: Maybe a video can help? Please look on following page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jnpC_Ib_lbc

Comment: pip.exe is just a wrapper executable to run pip's main script using python.exe. You cannot install Python using pip.